# ArcGIS Online Dashboard: Embed URL Using Rich Text

Tags: arcgis-online, html

Is it possible to embed a URL using "Rich Text" in ArcGIS Online Dashboards?

I want to have the text say "PLANNING AND ZONING DEPARTMENT" , and embed the URL so  users can directly access the city's planning department web page.

I have been trying a combination of these two templates with no success...

1.)  `<a href=http://www.example.com>Example</a>`

2.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Local Links</h2>

<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML Images</a> is a link to a page on this website.</p>

<p><a href="https://www.w3.org/">W3C</a> is a link to a website on the World Wide Web.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Rich Text element you can add to a dashboard.
Dropdown to Add Rich Text > Click Link > Type in Display Text > Type in URL > OK.

Alternatively, you can use the Link button in any of the other elements used to build the dashboard and do it the same way.